# What is the relationship between data science, artificial intelligence,machine learning and computer vision?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, terminology, data-science

I am beginner to this field and i am trying to find big picture and i have tried to explore youtube and google images in this regard. According to my understanding ,machine learning is subset of artificial intelligence . But what about computer vision and data science, are they also subset of artificial intelligence? Which is main set? Artificial intelligence or data science?

If someone can share a venn diagram that may be very helpful in understanding the proper placement/arrangement of above mentioned different fields

Answer (score 4):

This Venn diagram might help to visualize the relation between the different fields:

[image]

The image is from the free [deep learning book](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/intro.html) by Ian Goodfellow, Yoshua Bengio and Aaron Courville. As you said machine learning is indeed a subset of Artificial intelligence. Artificial intelligence is [since its origins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_artificial_intelligence) a very broad framework with a strong overlap with computer science, neuroscience, game theory, reinforcement learning, linguistics, etc. Computer vision can in general be considered a part of artificial intelligence. However, computer vision comes in various flavors and forms and some people in the field might not be fond of putting their work under the 'AI' umbrella. Data science conceptually overlaps with many of the methods used within AI but it is more focused on statistics, data analytics, modeling, and data mining.

In industry being a data scientist often means 'generating insights from data' (eg via AB testing) while working as something with AI in the title involves some kind of deep learning (eg for natural language understanding).

Answer (score 0):

While I cannot provide a Venn Diagram like the other answers, i can explain the relationship between them.

Computer vision is heavily tied in with AI, because computers have no intuitive sense of what a sign or word is. AI can help by using a training model with samples to tell it what a word in English or Russian is etc. Without AI computer vision is fiction. You cannot teach a computer to understand a sign without telling it what a sign usually looks like via sample data.

Data science can be somewhat connected to AI and Machine vision, but its usually just crunching numbers. For example, what is the most optimal way to recommend these videos to the users? Data science is wide so AI can be used for some jobs while statistics is used for another. Computers are used to solve most of the heavy work especially with algorithms.